# How to use Bean Methods in an imported JAR

Tags: java

I have a java class that i was tasked to relocate as a JAR. Now this class uses
a Bean from the original project. My question is that is there any way to use that bean inside this newly created JAR?

Example of a method inside a JAR that uses a bean (named MyBean) from another project:

```
      public String sendInfo(Direct dr, MyBean mb, int sm, int sn, MyMethod mmd, String Id, ReasonType rea) throws Exception {
        MyCreateModel mcm = createMyCreateModel(mb, sm, id, rea);

        Marshaller mr = JC.createMarshaller();
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        mr.marshal(fcm, sw);

//httpResponse call goes here
        
        MyBean bean = new MyBean(icp + msm.getProduct().getProduct().getId());

        String rtt = dr.takeTranactionStr(bean);
      
        dr.getTransaction().add(bean);

        if (false) {
            throw new Exception("Failure on method");
        }
        return msm.getCancellationId();
    }
```

Comment: Yes, as long my.package.MyBean is on your classpath. Did you get any error ? Post the message. Not very clear what issue you have.

Comment: Well that is the problem as I'm unable to import the bean on the newly created jar.

Comment: `I'm unable to import the bean`, sorry, can't follow you. You are getting a compiler error or ClassNotFoundException at runtime ?